# Netgear FVS336G as VPN Server

Tags: vpn, ipsec, netgear

One of our offices has made the move away from PFSense to a Netgear FVS336G. The one feature I can't seem to figure out is its VPN capabilities.

I'm confused as to whether this device can act as a IPSEC VPN server, or if it can only act as the client in a Site->Site VPN. The documentation does not make this clear at all, and Google does not seem to have been any help.

(Related question: [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/123176/question-about-remote-wan-ip-on-netgear-fvs336g-vpn-setup))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can be used as a VPN server, I'm just an idiot and missed that chapter of the user manual.